# Modify arguments of selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to setup a test environment for testing an appimage of an electron app via selenium. It's basically working, but I have a problem with the arguments. Without selenium, the usual call to the appimage is `app.AppImage --profile test` . However, when using the following script, the call is `app.AppImage --enable-logging --remote-debugging-port=0 --user-data-dir=/tmp/some/path`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver_service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service("./chromedriver")
chromedriver_service.start()

driver = webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver(
    command_executor=chromedriver_service.service_url,
    desired_capabilities={
        "goog:chromeOptions": {
            "binary": "app.AppImage",
            "excludeSwitches": [
                "disable-background-networking",
                "disable-client-side-phishing-detection",
                "disable-default-apps",
                "disable-hang-monitor",
                "disable-popup-blocking",
                "disable-prompt-on-repost",
                "disable-sync",
                "enable-automation",
                "enable-blink-features",
                "log-level",
                "no-first-run",
                "no-service-autorun",
                "password-store",
                "test-type",
                "use-mock-keychain",
            ],
        },
    },
)
```

How can I modify the arguments?

- More important: How to add `--profile test`? The obvious way would be to add `"args": ["--profile", "test"]` to chromeoptions. This does not work. Each list element will be handled as a separate argument.
- Less important: How to remove the other flags (mostly `--user-data-dir=`)? It seems to be not directly possible (see [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/85.0.4183.99:chrome/test/chromedriver/chrome_launcher.cc;l=142)).

Further information: The webdriver version is 85.0.4183.87.

Answer (score 0):

you should add args as :

```
args : ["--profile-directory=Profile 1","--profile=test"]
```

what ever you want to remove , add it inside the exclude switches array

```
 "excludeSwitches": [

               "user-data-dir",
                ...remaining things
            ],
```

Comment: The app expects the argument in space separated format, like `--profile test`. I can't change the format, so I can't use `--profile=test`.
`user-data-dir` inside the exclude switches is ignored, as the link shows. The option is still there.

Comment: @Marph remove equal and giver it as "--profile test"

Comment: it just sends each element as it is

Comment: `["--profile test"]` is interpreted as one argument, like `app.AppImage "--profile test"`. The app expects space separated arguments, like `app.AppImage --profile test`.